# strip the file path in Batch script

Tags: file, batch-file, path, strip

SourceFilePath="D:\Projects\Code\Site\Beanch\GV\dllfunction\dll_feature\filename.cpp"
How to strip folder names which is just before the file name

From the above example string, i want to get dll_feature,dllfunction,GV into different variables.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "SourceFilePath=D:\Projects\Code\Site\Beanch\GV\dllfunction\dll_feature\filename.cpp"
SET /a count=0
:loop
FOR %%a IN ("%sourcefilepath%") DO SET "part%count%=%%~nxa"&SET "sourcefilepath=%%~dpa"
IF DEFINED part%count% SET /a count +=1&SET "sourcefilepath=%sourcefilepath:~,-1%"&GOTO loop
SET part
SET count
GOTO :EOF
```

Provided you don'y have weirdo characters in the starting name...

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "sourceFilePath=D:\Projects\Code\Site\Beanch\GV\dllfunction\dll_feature\filename.cpp"

    set "count=10000"
    for %%a in ("%sourceFilePath:\=" "%") do (
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        for %%b in (!count:~-4!) do (
            endlocal 
            set "e_%%b=%%a"
        )
        set /a "count+=1"
    )

    rem Show the variables
    set e_
```

Separates each element in the variable replacing the backslash with a space (everything quoted to avoid problems) and for each element, a variable is defined

Numbers in variable names are padded. If not needed just change the initial `count` value to 0

Answer (score 0):

The one limitation that the MC ND's solution is that you must know the directory depth to get the parts at the end.

Here's an alternate strategy that employs recursion and subroutines. The "subroutine" `:SPLIT` gets the n<sup>th</sup> item from the specified path (0 is the right-most) and saves it into the variable specified. The way it's written, if you specify a *level* that is greater than the number of directory parts, it saves an empty string to the variable. This could be changed easily if that was desirable.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "SourceFilePath=D:\Projects\Code\Site\Beanch\GV\dllfunction\dll_feature\filename.cpp"

FOR /L %%i IN (0,1,10) DO (
    CALL :SPLIT "%SourceFilePath%" %%i TGT
    @ECHO [%%i] !TGT!
)
EXIT /B


REM   Syntax: CALL :SPLIT _path_ _level_
REM   Get the _nth_ element of the path (0 is the right-most)
:SPLIT
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "PATH=%~1"
SET "LEVEL=%~2"
SET "TARGET_VAR=%~3"

REM   Strip off a trailing dir sep (for the %%~ substitution).
IF "%PATH:~-1,1%"=="\" SET "PATH=!PATH:~0,-1!"

FOR %%p IN (%PATH%) DO (
    IF /I "%PATH%"=="%%~dp" (
        REM   BASE CASE
        IF "%LEVEL%"=="0" (
            SET "_TARGET=%PATH%"
        ) ELSE (
            SET "_TARGET="
        )
    ) ELSE IF "%LEVEL%"=="0" (
        REM   Return the leaf
        SET "_TARGET=%%~nxp"
    ) ELSE (
        REM   Recurse on the drive+directory
        SET /A SUBLEVEL=LEVEL-1
        CALL :SPLIT "%%~dpp" !SUBLEVEL! _TARGET
    )
)

ENDLOCAL && SET "%TARGET_VAR%=%_TARGET%"
EXIT /B
```

The output of this script is:

```
[0] filename.cpp
[1] dll_feature
[2] dllfunction
[3] GV
[4] Beanch
[5] Site
[6] Code
[7] Projects
[8] D:
[9] 
[10]
```

For the description you give, this invocation would give you something like you want:

```
CALL :SPLIT "%SourceFilePath%" 0 PART0
@ECHO %PART0%
CALL :SPLIT "%SourceFilePath%" 1 PART1
@ECHO %PART1%
CALL :SPLIT "%SourceFilePath%" 2 PART2
@ECHO %PART2%
```